# How to add a page_id in a php, when using childthemes?

Tags: php, wordpress, paragraph, child-theming

I need to add various content, including paragraphs to a wordpress-page, for a client. I am working through Wordpress/childthemes. For some wierd reason, the page I've been handed has no entry through the page-panel in Wordpress, nor does it have a page-id through which I can identitfy, so that I can edit it through functions.php or alike - all i have is a demo page. I need to place images and paragraphs.

```
  <html lang="en-US" class="js"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="pingback" href="http://danwise.democrunch.dk/xmlrpc.php">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.documentElement.className = 'js';
    </script>
```

I expect to find the page_id so that I can add HTML-content through a php-page in the childtheme

Answer (score 0):

You can add the standard class names (including the page IDs) by using WordPress's `body_class()` function. It would look like this:

```php
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

And output something like this:

```html
<body class="page page-id-2 page-parent page-template-default logged-in">
```

You can read more about this in the [WordPress docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/).

Comment: Thanks Tyler Willis. However I do not fully understand how I should substract the tag line, following the body class. I only have a demo page at this point - also i am very new to working with child themes.